# Networkctl: Manual VLAN IP Link

Tags: ip, systemd, systemd-networkd

I've a network interface `eth0` that carries my main network as untagged traffic and a "management" network with tagged traffic with the id `18`. This is how it's configured:

**10-eth0.network:**

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=yes

[Network]
DHCP=v4
VLAN=vlan18
```

**vlan18.netdev:**

```
[NetDev]
Name=vlan18
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=18
```

**vlan18.network:**

```
[Match]
Name=vlan18

[Network]
Address=10.10.1.1/24
```

On boot the server will start `eth0` get an IP via DHCP and also create `vlan18@eth0` for the "management" network with the static IP `10.10.1.1` and it all works.

**How can I tell networkctl to create the `vlan18@eth0` interface but without bringing it UP on boot?** The idea is to have a bunch of scripts that will do `ip link set vlan18 up` / `ip link set vlan18 down` to access to that network when required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this, according to the documentation, is to add `ActivationPolicy=manual` to the `Link` section of the network definition:

> **ActivationPolicy=**
>
> Specifies the policy for systemd-networkd managing the link administrative > state. Specifically, this controls how systemd-networkd changes the network device's "IFF_UP" flag, which is sometimes controlled by system administrators by running e.g., ip link set dev eth0 up or ip link set dev eth0 down, and can also be changed with networkctl up eth0 or networkctl down eth0.
>
> Takes one of "up", "always-up", "manual", "always-down", "down", or >"bound". **When "manual", systemd-networkd will not change the link's admin state >automatically; the system administrator must bring the interface up or down >manually, as desired.**

Source: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#ActivationPolicy=

**vlan18.network:**

```
[Match]
Name=vlan18

[Network]
Address=10.10.1.1/24

[Link]
ActivationPolicy=manual
```

Unfortunately as reported [here (github/systemd)](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/22593) and [here (superuser)](https://superuser.com/questions/1678714/configure-systemd-network-vlans-that-dont-auto-start) there seems to be a bug in systemd that makes it ignore `ActivationPolicy` in VLANs. The config applies to regular network interfaces with no problem.